# How do I get session data in Django?

Tags: django, python-2.7, session

Basically, what I'm looking for is the Django/Python equivalent to the PHP

```
session_start();
print_R($_SESSION);
```

That is, I'd like to dump all the information I currently have stored in the session so I can see what's in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The session is a [dict-like object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/sessions/#using-sessions-in-views) so you can simply `print request.session` to see what's in it.

The output will show up on the console of the server when using the development server - usually that's actually much better than `print_r` in PHP which dumps it to the webbrowser, next to whatever HTML you might have.

However, you could also `return HttpResponse(repr(request.session))` if you do want to send it to the browser.

Comment: What do you mean "The output will show up on the console of the server"? Are you saying I should use the REPL in the terminal? OR that it will appear in the console of the browser's developer tools?

Comment: Usually people use [`django-admin runserver`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/) during development. Anything you `print` in Python will show up there since `print` goes straight to stdout.

Comment: OCI. Thanks, bub!

Comment: There's no good reason to put the server into the background - but do consider using something like tmux so you can see its output and have a normal shell at the same time.

Comment: It's started up in it's own docker container, which I'm su-ing into with `docker exec`.

Answer (score 0):

Since Django middleware stores all session data in request, we can access the session data in any view.As session is just a python dictionary(key,value pair),all the data can be accessed just like a normal python dictionary.

To store the data in session just do:

```
request.session['USER_NAME'] = 'John'
```

Similarly, You can access it anywhere you have request object:

```
request.session.get('USER_NAME')
```

So,To see the actual dictionary you can either print or log:

```
request.session
```